# Keep `terser` from changing function argument names

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, terser

Let's say there's a function

```
function fname (arg1) {}
```

When `terser` minifies it, it changes both the function name and the argument names (by deafault)

I need to keep the argument name as is.
I've found a `--keep_fnames` option that solves the function rename, but I don't see any option to keep arguments from being renamed.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that this is a know issue.

The author is waiting for the upcoming `tc39/proposal-binary-ast` to be finalised, which could prevent the function source code from being given with the `functionObject.toString()` call.

No way to do it as it stands.

References:
[1]: https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/622
[2]: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-binary-ast#functionprototypetostring